# Jquery - Find a select element inside a parent DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I have a parent Div :

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContentAreaPlaceHolder_deliveryOpen" class="delivery_open" style="display: block;">

//Child select Element
<select class="txtfield ckgcountry" id="ctl00_MainContentAreaPlaceHolder_DeliveryPersonalInformation_country" name="ctl00$MainContentAreaPlaceHolder$DeliveryPersonalInformation$country"> 
 <option value="DE">ALLEMAGNE</option>
 <option value="TF">TERRES AUSTRALES FR.</option>
 <option value="TH">THAILANDE</option>

</select>   

</div>
```

I am trying to change the dropdown values selected item using :

```
$j("div[id*='deliveryOpen'] > .txtfield ckgcountry").removeAttr('selected');
```

OR

```
$j(".delivery_open > .txtfield ckgcountry").removeAttr('selected');
```

Both of these methods don't seem to work, what am i missing?, and also if theres a better (more efficient) way to achieve this?

Extra information:

I have 2 of the same elements with the same names (since its one custom control repeated). thus I cannot directly access the Select element, I have to go from the parent DIV and find the select element inside the parent DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error in your statements - you're trying to select the dropdown by class, so the selector should be `.ckgcountry` instead of `ckgcountry`. Also, I don't see a an element that would correspond to `.txtField`, so that could be causing failure as well.

However, you could use this as your selector:

```
$("select[id$='DeliveryPersonalInformation_country']")
```

I'm a little confused as to what you want to do with those `removeAttr('selected');` however. If you want to just select a different option, try:

```
$("select[id$='DeliveryPersonalInformation_country']").val("TF");
```

Comment: I have 2 of the same elements with the same names (since its one custom control repeated. thus I cannot directly access the Select element, I have to go from the parent DIV and find the select element inside the parent DIV.

Comment: If the divs are uniquely named, then your original selectors are probably quite close to what you want (minus the .txtField selector): $("div[id$='deliveryOpen'] > .ckgcountry").val("TF").

Based on your description, I think you'll want to go with an id attribute selector for the div rather than the class selector.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you access to the `<select>` element and allow you manipulate it's attributes.  For example;

```
$j('.delivery_open > .txtfield.ckgcountry').attr('value', 'DE');
```

Or (I think this one is a safer option - based on my gut feeling)

```
$('.delivery_open > .txtfield.ckgcountry').attr('selectedIndex', 2);
```

Not entirely sure what you need to do with the `<select>` element, so the above examples are only a guide.